# Options such as expandtab reset based on which file I edit

Tags: set

My `~/.vimrc` contains the following:

```
set noet
set ts=8
set sw=8
```

When I open vim without arguments:

`:set et?` -> `noexpandtab`

and

`:set sw?` ->   `shiftwidth=8`

but when I open a file: `:e somefile.py`

`:set et?` ->   `expandtab`

and

`:set sw?` ->   `shiftwidth=4`

but editing `~/.vimrc` yields the same results like when I opened vim without arguments

Why does this happen and how to fix it?

Comment: I’m looking for a duplicate that I though existed, but in short `:help ftplugin`, `:help setlocal`

Comment: [Set tab as 2 spaces in vimrc, but still set to 4 spaces when editing python files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56408989/set-tab-as-2-spaces-in-vimrc-but-still-set-to-4-spaces-when-editing-python-file)

Comment: I seem various pythonistas had asked this question 1000 times already. But, perhaps, they all were on main SO site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vim may override your global settings with filetype-specific settings through [filetype plugins](https://vimhelp.org/filetype.txt.html#filetype-plugins). (There are also indent plugins that can affect this behavior.)

In the specific case of Python shift width and tab expansion, this behavior is enabled by script [`$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/python.vim`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/v8.2.0/runtime/ftplugin/python.vim#L118) which ships with Vim.

Note that, in the specific case of the Python options you mentioned, you can override them by setting a global variable to tell Vim you'd like it *not* to set them. You can do so by adding this variable setting to your vimrc:

```
let g:python_recommended_style = 0
```

This behavior (and the variable to override it) is documented under [`:help ft-python-plugin`](https://vimhelp.org/filetype.txt.html#ft-python-plugin).

Comment: How about `:filetype off` to disable filetype detection, filetype plugins and indent plugins?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Yes, that works, of course, but it has many other side effects, such as disabling syntax highlighting... Perhaps disabling only ftplugins (and perhaps indent), leaving detection enabled, is a more targeted solution. But it might end up disabling some parts that you like to have.

Comment: This solves the problem for Python, thanks!
But how to I disable all filetype plugins without disabling filetype detection? Putting `filetype indent plugin off` into my vimrc didn't disable everything: `tw` is still set to 78 in plain text files even though its set to 0 in my vimrc

Comment: @lsmw Can you check what `:verbose set tw?` says while you're editing a plain text file? That should tell you about where this setting is coming from...

Comment: @filbranden `Last set from /etc/vim/vimrc line 160` - apparently my distro is overwriting my local vimrc, thanks for your help!